# Show the following inequality in measure.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, M, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f_n \rightarrow f$ everywhere on $X$. Then for every $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, we have:
$$\mu\{f>\alpha\} \leq \liminf \mu \{f_n \geq \alpha\}.$$

> Attempt of proof: Let $E:= \{f > \alpha\}$ and $E_n := \{f_n > \alpha\}$. Since $f_n \rightarrow f$ on $X$, $\chi_{E_n} \rightarrow \chi_E$ on $E$, and $\chi_E \equiv 1$ on $E$. Hence,
> $$\mu(E) = \int_E \chi_E \leq \liminf \int_E \chi_{E_n} \leq \int_{E_n} 1 = \mu(E_n).$$
> Also, note that $\mu(E_n) \leq \mu(\{f_n \geq \alpha\})$. Hence, $\mu(E) \leq \liminf \mu(\{f_n\geq \alpha\})$.

I feel that notes I have involve lot of unnecessary steps, and I am wondering if what I have above is a correct proof. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems correct to me

Answer (score 0):

The argument $\mathbb{1}_{E_n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow}\mathbb{1}_E$ in the OP deserves a few words.
From $f_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f$ pointwise, one can deduce
$$\{f>\alpha\}\subset\bigcup_n\bigcap_{m\geq n}\{f_m>\alpha\}=\liminf_n\{f_n>\alpha\}$$
The $\sigma$-continuity of $\mu$ and the fact that $\bigcap_{m\geq n}\{f_m>\alpha\}\subset \{f_n>\alpha\}$ imply that
\begin{align}
\mu(f>\alpha)&\leq\mu(\liminf_n\{f_n>\alpha\})=\lim_n\mu\big(\bigcap_{m\geq n}\{f_m>\alpha\}\Big)\\
&\leq\liminf_n\mu(f_n>a)\leq\liminf_n\mu(f_n\geq \alpha)\end{align}